# Is there a better way of selecting between arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, singleton

I have a structure that includes a function, and that function uses a dataset decided by some variable. I have a solution, but it seems like there would be a better way of solving this.

Here's some example code:

```swift
struct TextStyles {
    let format: UTType

    static var asm: [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] = [: /* ... */]
    static var txt: [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] = [: /* ... */]
    
    func getAppropriateDataset() -> [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] {
        switch format {
            case "asm": return TextStyles.asm
            case "txt": return TextStyles.txt
            // returns empty
            default: return .init()
        }
    }
}

struct HighlightDelegate {
    let format: UTType
    lazy var styleSelector: TextStyles(format: format)

    func applyHighlights(for text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        // Should always produce the same key/value list, because `format` never changes
        styleSelector.getAppropriateDataset()
    }
}
```

Is there any common practise to create such singleton? The function always produces the same list, so is there any native or "better" way of solving this problem? It would be beneficial if it could be written like something like this:

```swift
struct HighlightDelegate {
    let format: UTType
    lazy var styleUsed = TextStyles.getStyleArray(forFormat: format)
    // or even better, perhaps?: TextStyles(forFormat: format)

    func applyHighlights(for text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        // `styleUsed` is the array for this HighlightDelegate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I can use an `enum` to select between the arrays, and a static method that returns one of the values.

```swift
enum TextStyles {
    static let asm: [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] = [: /* ... */]
    static let txt: [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] = [: /* ... */]
    
    static func getAppropriateDataset(for format: UTType) -> [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] {
        switch format {
            case .asm: return TextStyles.asm
            case .txt: return TextStyles.txt
            // returns empty
            default: return [:]
        }
    }
}
```

The example usage:

```swift
struct HighlightDelegate {
    let format: UTType
    lazy var style = TextStyles.getAppropriateDataset(for: format)

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely understand your question, but I am using an answer instead of a comment so that I can include code well.

If I can guess, I think you're reaching for an extension.

```swift
extension UTType {
    var styles: [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] {
        switch self {
            ...
        }
    }
}

struct HighlightDelegate {
    let format: UTType

    func applyHighlights(for text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        ...
        format.styles
        ...
    }
}
```

If you really want `styles` to be a property of `HighlightDelegate`, you can do

```swift
struct HighlightDelegate {
    let format: UTType
    var styles: [NSRegularExpression: NSColor] { format.styles }

    func applyHighlights(for text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        ...
        styles
        ...
    }
}
```

or if you actually want to cache the styles (seems unnecessary to me, but you could)

```
class HighlightDelegate {
    let format: UTType
    lazy var styles = format.styles

    func applyHighlights(for text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        ...
        styles
        ...
    }

    init(format: UTType) {
        self.format = format
    }
}
```

In this case, you much use a class because accessing a lazy property of a struct is mutating (it will change the bits of the struct on the first access).

If it is important to keep the `TextStyles` type around, you can modify this code accordingly. If this isn't what you were looking for, please comment.

Comment: I aso figured that I could use enums for this, and have a static method that returns any array dependant on the value I pass. I guess this works as well without modifying `UTType`